# I have an 'UsageError' on SailsJs with waterline-orm model method '.archive()'

Tags: sails.js, waterline

this is error return in postman when i try to archive a record in my Sails backend.

**UsageError: Invalid initial data for new records.\nDetails:\n  Could not use one of the provided new records: Missing value for required attribute `id`.  Expected a string, but instead, got: undefined\n [?] See https://sailsjs.com/support for help**

Please somebody know what this error means? Thanks in advance.

Thanks for your response
My code:
- In controller:

```
try {
      await Laboratory.archive({id: inputs.id});
    } catch (error) {
      console.log('Error-6 CORE-DELETE_LABORATORY:', error)
      exits.failed(`Error-6 CORE-DELETE_LABORATORY: ${error}${inputs.id}`)}
```

In file config/models.js:

```
module.exports.models = {

  migrate: 'alter',

  fetchRecordsOnUpdate: true,
  fetchRecordsOnCreate: true,
  fetchRecordsOnCreateEach: true,

  attributes: {

    createdAt: { type: 'ref', columnType: 'datetime', autoCreatedAt: true, },
    updatedAt: { type: 'ref', columnType: 'datetime', autoUpdatedAt: true, },

    id: { type: 'string', columnName: '_id' },
  },

  dataEncryptionKeys: {
    default: 'dRYQHBf8Zpza2vMS5BB3qcSiLspJP4BG37I2JkP2yYw='
  },

  cascadeOnDestroy: true
};
```

Laboratory model:

```
module.exports = {

  attributes: {
    type: {
      type: 'string',
      isIn: ['INSIDE', 'OUTSIDE'],
      required: true,
    },
    raisonSocial: {
      type: 'string',
      required: true,
      unique: true,
    },

    city: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    address: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    email: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    neighborhood: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    contacts: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    logo: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    lat: {
      description: 'Latitude',
      type: 'number'
    },

    long: {
      description: 'Longitude',
      type: 'number'
    },

    website: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    subdomain: {
      type: 'string',
      unique: true,
      required: true,
    },

    mobileMoney: {
      type: 'string'
    },

    bank: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },
    bankAccountID: {
      type: 'string',
      defaultsTo: ''
    },

    validated : {
      type: 'boolean',
      defaultsTo : false
    },

    f_establishment: {
      model: 'establishment'
    },

    director: {
      description: 'Chef of laboratory id',
      type: 'json',
      example: '{name, phone, role}',
      required: true,
    }
  },

  customToJSON () {
    if (this.logo) {
      this.logo = `${process.env.BASE_URL}/avatar/${this.logo}`
    }
    return this
  }
};
```

Thanks.

Comment: It would probably be great to post some code for the SailsJS backend, it's much easier to help with some code. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Sails throws `UsageError` when we use a db method in an incorrect way. To be more precise, this is what Sails has in its documentation.

> When an error has name: 'UsageError', this indicates that a Waterline
> method was used incorrectly, or executed with invalid options (for
> example, attempting to create a new record that would violate one of
> your model's high-level validation rules.)
>
> https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/models-and-orm/errors#?usage-errors

To give you a simple example, if you have a db query with limit parameter and you start passing string values for that parameter, Sails with start throwing `UsageError`.

In your case, things should be self explanatory from the error detail itself. Your code flow is getting `undefined` for `inputs.id` when it tries to run `Laboratory.archive({id: inputs.id})` but `id` is expected to be a string if you see `config/models.js`.

Just do a basic debugging to see why `inputs.id` is coming as undefined and solve that issue, and you should be good to go.